# Why the name 'Rogue One'?

Tags: star-wars, names, rogue-one

So far, is there any suggestion, or speculation as to the reason for the name 'Rogue One' for the next Star Wars film?

To me, the name seems very close to the Rogue Squadron, most known from Hoth (their leader Luke Skywalker), especially the number following Rogue like a callsign.

However as far as I know, they were formed after the first Death Star destruction. So why Rogue One?

Comment: It will probably be expanded upon in the film. As it's a future work, we can't really say, except possibly in an out-of-universe answer.

Comment: Yep, this crossed my mind, but I wasn't sure it fits, partly it's not 'A rogue one', it would fit though if the film is strongly focused on the character we see in the trailer.

Comment: Now that the movie is released: Rogue One is a callsign the crew comes up with on the spot when asked for their callsign.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page for Rogue Squadron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_Squadron) suggests that Rogue Group and/or Rogue Squadron was named in honor of the Rogue One team.

Answer (score 23):

We learn in the film that the name "Rogue One" refers to the [callsign](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One_(squad)) of the squad that went to capture the plans for the Death Star. Since the film revolves around the origin story of this odd rag-tag group of rebels, naming the film after them seems most appropriate.

[image]

The name apparently resonated with the film's director, Gareth Edwards for a number of different reasons, referring to the film, the call sign of the unit but also the main character Jyn Erso.

> *"I'd been thinking about it,” he reflects in the new issue of Empire. “What does it mean? **'Rogue One’ is a military call sign to some extent,”** he adds, referring to Red Squadron during the Battle of Yavin, **"but this is the first film that's gone off-piste and is not part of the saga – or the Anakin story – so it’s the 'rogue' one, you know?”***
>
> ***There’s potentially another meaning to it too, relating to Felicity Jones’ interplanetary guerrilla Jyn Erso.** She also has a rogue streak; a touch of the Han Solos in her drive to do what’s right, regardless of how much shit she has to blow up en route. **“It's kind of describing her as well in a similar way,”** says Edwards. “It has [all] these split, multiple meanings that made it feel like the right choice."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Exclusive: Rogue One’s Gareth Edwards explains the movie's title](http://www.empireonline.com/people/ben-mendelsohn/exclusive-rogue-one-gareth-edwards-explains-movie-title/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Sure. Downvote an answer that has a quote from the director explaining precisely why he chose the name.

Comment: What I want to know: Since Bodhi Rook had to think of a call sign in a matter of seconds under pressure, didn't he luck out a bit that the very cool "Rogue One" popped into his head? What if the only thing to pop into his head was "Fuzzy Pink Nerfherders" (or worse). Would this mean the title of the movie would have been "Fuzzy Pink Nerfherders"?

Answer (score -1):

Rogue Squadron existed and was famous some years before Hoth - so, there is no time inconsistency.

Not only you think that "Rogue One" refers to "Rogue Squadron":

> Rogue One likely references the title given to Rogue Leader, or the commander of the Rebel Alliance's most elite starfighter squadron, Rogue Squadron. The title is one of honor and respect, and is usually handed out to the best pilot in the Defense Force. There have been multiple Rogue Leaders over the years, from Wedge Antilles to Tycho Celchu, though none have been quite as famous as a certain Jedi you might have heard of: Luke Skywalker.
>   <sub>- [CinemaBlend](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Star-Wars-Spinoff-Finally-Has-Title-70270.html)</sub>

Comment: Is there any information about rogue squadron existing before?

Comment: "Rouge Squadron existed and was famous for some years before Hot - so there is no time inconsistency" not really. The OP was asking why it was called Rouge One if Rouge Squadron was formed after the Death Star I was destroyed yet the movie takes place directly before ANH

Comment: @TheMandolorian I find your repeated misspell of "Rogue" disturbing...